# How to know which params is missing in a query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm setting up a Booking router in NodeJS, and I have many params in.
Now when I forgot params I return an error like :

500: Need more information

I wonder if it's possible to know which params are missing when I return the error code.

This is for a new API made in NodeJS

Here are the params that I want to retrieve from the front ( made in ReactJS )

```
let body = {
        agentDutyCode: "STRING",
        RatePlanCode: params.rateCode,
        RoomCode: params.roomCode,
        AmountAfterTax: params.amountTax,
        Start: params.fromDate,
        End: params.toDate,
        CardCode: params.cardCode,
        CardNumber: params.cardNumber,
        ExpireDate: params.expireDate,
        SeriesCode: params.cvv,
        CardHolderName: params.nameCard,
        ChainCode: params.chainCode,
        HotelCode: params.hotelCode,
        RoomQuantities: params.roomQuantities,
        GuestQuantitie: params.numberGuest,
        GuestPerRoom: params.guestPerRoom,
        LastName: params.lastName,
        FirstName: params.firstName,
        PhoneNumber: params.phoneNumber,
        email: params.email,
        FVL_SUBUNIT_7: params.walletAddress
    }
```

And this is my promise :

```js
 cdsJson.bookResource(req.body)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response !== null) {
                res.response = {
                    ...response
                }
            } if (response.hotel.length === 0) {
                res.respStatus = 500
                res.response = {
                    sendMsg: "Need more informations"
                }
                next('route')
            }
            return response
        })
```

If the request succeeds I got a reservation ID otherwise I got :

Error 500: Need more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation or the source code.

Seriously. If the API response doesn't tell you in the error message, then there is no way to know what parameters it expects programmatically.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right. I'll call the API admin.

Answer (score 1):

try it for a `for ... in` loop like this:

```
cdsJson.bookResource(req.body)
.then((response) => {
    if (response !== null) {
        res.response = {
            ...response
        }
    } if (response.hotel.length === 0) {
        res.respStatus = 500

        let errorStr = "Need more informations"

        for(var key in req.body) { // Get all parameters that are not set
            if(objects[key] == undefined)
                errorStr += "\nParameter ["+key+"] is missing!"
        }

        res.response = {
            sendMsg: errorStr
        }
        next('route')
    }
    return response
})
```

Comment: Thank you, your method doesn't work because the API that I call is not mine.

Comment: You wrote `this is my promise`. So I aussume this is code from you or not? @EythanFellous

Comment: So why cant you change it then? @EythanFellous

Comment: Misunderstoond ^^, the API doesn't return any information of what is missing or which params is wrong.

Comment: Yeah thats true, but you can still check what you are sending or not. And with that you can give the user a hint which parameters are missing. @EythanFellous

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do server side validation. In Node a good approach would be to define a JSON Schema for the expected parameters and then in your route handler validate the data sent in the request with a JSON Schema validator. This would help you work out whether a request was valid *and* help you generate error messages automatically. As a rule it's much better (i.e. simpler and more maintainable) to use tools that enable you to declaratively declare your validation (via a schema) than imperatively write code to manually validate objects.

- JSON Schema spec https://json-schema.org/
- A validator https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

Comment: I already have a Validator in my code, but thank you for the lead